# How run a script only on the homepage?

Tags: javascript

There is a way to run the follow script only on the homepage?

```
<script>

   let changelink = document.querySelector('#app > div.boxes.cf > a');

   changelink.outerHTML = '<a href="#contact">contact us</a>';

</script>
```

I have tried this but it is not working. The script is still running on all the pages

```
<script>

   if (window.location.href.indexOf('/') != -1) {
    
      let changelink = document.querySelector('#app > div.boxes.cf > a');
    
      changelink.outerHTML = '<a href="#contact">contact us</a>';
   }

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only on the homepage"? What other pages are executing this script and how does it end up being embedded there?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#app > div.boxes.cf > a')` <-- You can't use `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` until DOMContentLoaded *or* if your `<script>` is located _after_ the desired elements in the source HTML.

Comment: Strange question.  This `<script>` tag appears in some HTML that was transmitted to the browser.  The script will run when that script tag is added to the DOM.   I'm confused about when you want it *not* to run?  Is this HTML fragment a template of some kind that is used to render more than one page?  Are you maybe using single-page-application (SPA) navigation like routers?

Comment: The reason why I am asking this is because that I am getting a null error --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'outerHTML') when I am in other page which is not homepage. That selector is only located on the homepage.

Comment: Did you look at what `window.location.href` returns? `console.log(window.location.href)` would clearly show what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
if (window.location.href.replaceAll(window.location.origin, '').replaceAll('/','').length === 0 ) {

  let changelink = document.querySelector('#app > div.boxes.cf > a');

  changelink.outerHTML = '<a href="#contact">contact us</a>';

}
```